# Define a Function that Returns a Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would I write the notation for a function that returns a set? For example this function would take in a parameter $x$ and spit out a set. Could I write it something like this: $F(x) = \{ b \;|\; b > x \wedge \cdots \}$?

Comment: What you suggest would be correct.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets, then it is perfectly reasonable to define a function $F : X \to \mathscr{P}(Y)$.  The notation $F(x) = \{ b : b > x\}$ would be one way of defining an example of such a function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one way to answer your question because it depends on what you want to do. But it is just a matter of specifying, either mathematically or in words, what you want the function to do. In standard examples, this is simple: $f(x):= x^2$. So $f$ takes a real number $x$, and returns its square. But for functions which return sets, this can be more difficult:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(A)&:= \{ a \in A \;|\; a>0 \} \\
g(I)&:= \{a,b\} \\
h(S)&:= \mathcal{P}(S)
\end{aligned}
$$
The function $f$ takes a subset of the real numbers $A$ and returns subset of $A$ consisting of all positive numbers in $A$. The function $g$ takes an interval $I=[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and returns a set consisting of its maximum and minimum values. The function $h$ takes a finite set $S$ and returns its power set, i.e. $h(\{a,b,c\})= \{\,\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\,\}$.

Notice in this last case, we cannot write down an explicit description of $h$, but the function is given by a process: take the set $S$, and form its power set. You could take this to extremes: let $j(\mathbf{v})$ be the function which takes a direction vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, creates the ray through the origin in that direction, finds its intersection with the unit sphere, say $(x,y,z)$, and returns the set of solutions $(a,b,c)$ (possibly empty) to $\sin(xa) - \sin(yb) = \sin(zc)$. We certainly cannot write down any easy description of $j(\mathbf{v})$, but we can explain what the function is. [But now we really need justify that $j$ is even a function!]

The (best) ways of writing the function depends on the function and the context! The key is to be clear, concise, and to be sure the function does what you want!

Comment: If $h$ operates on *all* finite sets, then it is not an ordinary function but a class function (because the finite sets form a proper class). But you can still write it down explicitly: Be $F$ the class of finite sets. Then $h(S)=\{A\in F\mid A\subseteq S\}$. Alternatively you can specify it explicitly by a logical formula: $\forall A\colon A\in f(S)\iff A\subseteq S$.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to specify $F$ for the first form. Just write $h(S)=\{A\mid A\subseteq F\}$. That doesn't specify the domain, but neither does $f(x)=x^2$ or $g(I)=\{a,b\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A common set value function is the set extension of f:X -> Y,
f':P(X) -> P(Y), A -> { f(x) : x in A }.
This function is notated f[A] = { f(x) : x in A }.
It always has an inverse f$^{-1}$[B] = { x : f(x) in B }.